# I want a spinner to be displayed when an item in a listview is clicked. How to do that?

Tags: android, listview, spinner, android-spinner

I have a listview containing 4 items. Whenever one of them is clicked, a pop up spinner should be displayed. I have populated the spinner adapter but I don't know how to display it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_community);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_community);

    list_c = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.community);

    cAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Community.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_c);

    listView.setAdapter(cAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0: list_sc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Spr_subclass);
                        scAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Community.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list_sc);
                        break;

                case 1: list_sc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Edu_subclass);
                        scAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Community.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list_sc);
                        break;

                case 2: list_sc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Coo_subclass);
                        scAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Community.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list_sc);
                        break;

                case 3: list_sc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Com_subclass);
                        scAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Community.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list_sc);
                        break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
public void showSpinnerPopUp(String[] array){

 AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(this);
 b.setTitle("Example");

 b.setItems(array, new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        switch(which){

        }
    }

});

 b.show();
}
```

And do this in item click

`showSpinnerPopUp(list_c)`;

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks! :)